# jquery slide up / slide down code almost perfect

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

I got this wonderful code from "deifwud" recently:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(".slide").hide();

$('a.link').on('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  var slideSelector = '#' + $(this).attr('id').replace('link', 'slide');

  // or do it in the reverse order
  $('div.slide').not($(slideSelector)).slideUp(500, function() {
    $(slideSelector).slideDown(500);
  });


  });      

});
```

I want to "split" the code somehow so that I can decide (in css?) which div slides down when a link is clicked and which div slides up.

in [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/NL9we/) example you will see 3 links. I would like "link 3" to slide up and "link 1" and "link 2" to slidedown like they are doing at the moment.

Would love to hear from you! Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW it sould be `$('div.slide').not(slideSelector)`

Answer (score 0):

chek this Edit [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/NL9we/2/)
,but your link 3 not a toggle link.

Comment: thanks, but there should never be more than one div on the screen.

Comment: hm... but now it is the same as it was. How can I let div3 slide up from the bottom?